# interagir com Select option dinamicamente via javascript

Tags: javascript, html-select, html-option, selected-option

creio que isso sejá muito simples, mas por azar, o mais simples é o mais complicado para eu compreender. lol

meu objetivo é simples e resumindo ele mais, fazer com que, quando você selecionar uma opção do select, baseado no valor da option, algo no html seria escrito, porém por alguma razão, mesmo eu alterando e refazendo e até mesmo quase copiando um código ( o que me fez criar essa conta aqui e fazer essa pergunta) o value selecionado era sempre "1". irei escrever um html/js

```
**HTML**
<div id="escrever"> </div>
<select name="prazo" id="prazoTest">
    <option value="1">1 dia</option>
    <option value="2">2 dias</option>
    <option value="4">4 dias</option>
    <option value="6">6 dias</option>
    <option value="7">1 semana</option>
</select>
```

js para mostrar que o problema que ocorria.

```
const selecter = document.getElementById('prazoTest')
const valueSelect = selecter.options[selecter.selectedIndex].value
const modificar = document.getEelementById('escrever')
            
function passarAfaca() {
    console.log(valueSelect)
    modificar.innerHTML = valueSelect
}
selecter.onchange = passarAfaca
```

Answer (score 1):

Para registrar uma escuta de evento em um elemento use o método `Element.addEventListener()`, passe no primeiro parâmetro o [tipo de evento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/type) que ficará em aguardo e no segundo uma [função](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) que receberá uma notificação quando um evento do tipo especificado ocorrer.

```js
const selecter = document.getElementById('prazoTest')
const modificar = document.getElementById('escrever')

selecter.addEventListener("change",function (e){
  console.log(e.target.value);
  modificar.innerText = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<div id="escrever"> </div>
<select name="prazo" id="prazoTest">
  <option value="1">1 dia</option>
  <option value="2">2 dias</option>
  <option value="4">4 dias</option>
  <option value="6">6 dias</option>
  <option value="7">1 semana</option>
</select>
```